# How to mock a class without default constructor using Mock.Of<T>()?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Using Moq, I need to create a fake over an existing **class** (not interface*) that has **no default ctor**.

I can do this using the "traditional" syntax:

```
var fakeResponsePacket = new Mock<DataResponse>(
    new object[]{0, 0, 0, new byte[0]}); //specify ctor arguments

fakeResponsePacket.Setup(p => p.DataLength).Returns(5);

var checkResult = sut.Check(fakeResponsePacket.Object);
```

My question is: Is there a way to do the same using the newer `Mock.Of<T>()` syntax ?

From what I can see, there are only two overloads for `Mock.Of<T>`, none of which accept arguments:

```
//1 no params at all
var fakeResponsePacket = Mock.Of<DataResponse>(/*??*/);
fakeResponsePacket.DataLength = 5;

//2 the touted 'linq to Moq'
var fakeResponsePacket = Mock.Of<DataResponse>(/*??*/
    p => p.DataLength == 5
);

var checkResult = sut.Check(fakeResponsePacket);
```

--
* I *wanted* to use an interface. But then reality happened. Let's not go into it.

Answer (score 4):

No, there appears to be no way of doing that.

<strike>Side-remark: In the "old" syntax, you can just write:</strike>

```
new Mock<DataResponse>(0, 0, 0, new byte[0]) //specify ctor arguments
```

since the array parameter there is `params` (a [parameter array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)).

To get around the issue with `0` being converted to a `MockBehavior` (see comments and crossed out text above), you could either do:

```
new Mock<DataResponse>(MockBehavior.Loose, 0, 0, 0, new byte[0]) //specify ctor arguments
```

or do:

```
var v = 0; // this v cannot be const!
// ...
new Mock<DataResponse>(v, 0, 0, new byte[0]) //specify ctor arguments
```

but this is not really part of what you ask, of course.

Comment: Actually, at least in this particular case, it won't work. There exists an overload `Mock<T>(MockBehavior, Object[])` and the first '0' will be cast to its enum equivalent MockBehaviour.Default. The rest of the parameters will be used for the ctor, and the operation will fail saying that no ctor exists that takes only 3 arguments.

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu Of course, I did not think of that. And the first constructor parameter is of type `int`, right? _Edit:_ I mean in the desired instance constructor overload of your `DataResponse` class, the first parameter is declared with type `int`.

Comment: yep. That's why I used an explicit array