# How to Mock a class having no default construtor

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I want to mock a class having no default constructor and call a method inside it. This method calls another method of the same class. I want to setup this second method to return a value ad execute rest of the part of first method to test some results.

```
[Test]
public void TestFunction(){
    int d=0;
    var mockObject = new Mock<Foo>(){MockBehaviour.Default, p, q}; //p and q are parameters for Foo constructor
    mockObject.Setup(x=>x.func2(a,b,c)).Returns(d);
    mockobject.Object.func1();
}


Class Foo{
    public Foo(int x,int y){}

    public virtual int func1(){
       DoSomething;
       func2();
    }

    public virtual int func2(){}
}
```

I am mocking Foo because I don't want func2() to be executed when I test func1(). Hence I setup the mockObject to return a value for func2() without executing it when func1() calls func2().

When I run this test case I get exception "System.NotSupportedException : Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined."

If I see the mockObject while debugging the test case, mockObject.Object is not getting initialized. 
I am new to unit testing and Mock. Can someone help me about where I am going wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you're in a bit of a mess here if I'm honest. Why does your test care what this other method is doing? If it's relying on "something" else, then that dependency should be injected in. That way, you can mock the dependency quite simple.

Comment: @DavidG Seems like the system under test depends on another of its methods, which OP already tested and tus want to mock.

Comment: Usually you shouldn´t mock a system under test. You may however subclass `Foo` and override the method you wanted to mock (which is essentially the same way Moq also works). However this assumes your method to be `virtual` in `Foo`.

Comment: If you want to unit test class `Foo` then you are, not supposed to mock it. Just create an instance of the class and call method on it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes I realise that, but I'm saying the class in question is too complex, possibly violating the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @DavidG Yes it does violate single responsibility but this is a legacy code so I don't have the permissions to modify it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The methods I want to test is virtual. The problem here is about the constructors of Foo.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I want to mock Foo because I want to setup returns of func2 so that it won't be executed when I test func1. Because func2 is already tested so I executing it is unnecessary.

Comment: You can not test a class partially using mock. Mock is a mocked object... not the actual object... So it does not represent the actual code of your class. When one method is calling another method and they both are public, you can not mock output of them.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your actual question:

> How to Mock a class having no default construtor

You need to use a different overload of the Mock ctor so that arguments are passed to the non-default Foo ctor:

```
  var mockObject = new Mock<Foo>(1, 2);
```

However your testing strategy is flawed and I believe this is due to how you understand Moq to function.

Mocks are useful for trivializing complex dependencies of what you are testing - instead of instantiating, handling their lifecycles, you mock them. This is okay when they don't affect the code you are actively testing (as others have mentioned in this question) -- that is not your intent here. Since Func2() is **tightly coupled** to the implementation of func1(), the way that the code is written now, there is not a way to execute Func1() without executing Func2().

You could change the function signature of Func1() to take Func2() as an argument -- this would allow you to modify which function is passed to it during testing (and allow you to Mock the behavior of Func2() easily. However you've already said this is an impossibility.

Comment: Func1() and Func2() are not private. And I need to mock Foo because I dont want func2 to be executed when I test func1. If i don't mock it then func2 will be called while testing func1 which is not needed. And this is a legacy code written 10 years back so I cannot change the code since it will affect the whole application.

Comment: @komalThawani - you updated your question to change Func1() and Func2() from being private to public - I'll update my answer also.

Answer (score 2):

Too answer your question being posted you may simply provide the arguments, as suggested in [this thread:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960559/how-to-mock-a-class-without-default-constructor-using-mock-oft)

```
var mockObject = new Mock<Foo>(MockBehaviour.Default, FooParameters);
mockObject.Setup(x=>x.func2(a,b,c)).Returns(d);
mockobject.Object.func1();
```

However this isn´t a good idea though. Usually you shouldn´t mock your system under test. Doing so may indicate that your class is doing too much and needs to be restructured, in order to do exactly one single thing.

However there may be situations where a class has several API-members that depend on each other. Think of an overload-chain where you want to test multiple overloads. Of course it´s easy to write a test for the most inner overload (with most params). However if want to test if your other overloads set the params for the most inner one correctly, you´re indeed stuck.

```
void DoSomething()
{
    var param = ...
    DoSomething(param);
}
void DoSomething(int p)
{
    // the most inner overload
}
```

There isn´t a general rule how to solve that dependency. I tend do subclass my system-under test in those cases and override its (`virtual`) members with an empty body - which is what MOQ internally does also.